# Providing a wrong CAS number into the visa application form

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

When I submitted my Tier 4 visa application form, I put the application number instead of CAS (*Confirmation of Acceptance for Studies*) number.
I *have* included a copy of the CAS  with my documents. Will I get a visa refusal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clerical error in Tier 4 student visa application](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/clerical-error-in-tier-4-student-visa-application)

Comment: What country's visa are we talking about? The UK?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the Border Agency official will be checking the CAS certificate you provided as well as your supporting documents.  If all is in order, you should not be refused for inserting the incorrect number on the application form.